# How to use a Python function in Julia?

Tags: python, julia

I would like to use [this Python function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/batch_normalization) in Julia.

In this way, I used:

```
using PyCall
@pyimport tensorflow
```

But there is the following error:

```
ERROR: PyError (ccall(@pysym(:PyImport_ImportModule), PyPtr, (Cstring,), name)

The Python package tensorflow could not be found by pyimport. Usually this means
that you did not install tensorflow in the Python version being used by PyCall.

PyCall is currently configured to use the Julia-specific Python distribution
installed by the Conda.jl package.  To install the tensorflow module, you can
use `pyimport_conda("tensorflow", PKG)`, where PKG is the Anaconda
package the contains the module tensorflow, or alternatively you can use the
Conda package directly (via `using Conda` followed by `Conda.add` etcetera).

Alternatively, if you want to use a different Python distribution on your
system, such as a system-wide Python (as opposed to the Julia-specific Python),
you can re-configure PyCall with that Python.   As explained in the PyCall
documentation, set ENV["PYTHON"] to the path/name of the python executable
you want to use, run Pkg.build("PyCall"), and re-launch Julia.

) <type 'exceptions.ImportError'>
ImportError('Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/home/jabou/.julia/v0.6/Conda/deps/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>\n    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *\n  File "/home/jabou/.julia/v0.6/Conda/deps/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in<module>\n    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()\n  File "/home/jabou/.julia/v0.6/Conda/deps/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper\n    _mod = imp.load_module(\'_pywrap_tensorflow_internal\', fp, pathname, description)\nImportError: /home/jabou/.julia/v0.6/Conda/deps/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10tensorflow10FileSystem16GetMatchingPathsERKSsPSt6vectorISsSaISsEE\n\n\nFailed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.\n\nSee https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems\n\nfor some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace\nabove this error message when asking for help.',)
  File "/home/jabou/.julia/v0.6/Conda/deps/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/home/jabou/.julia/v0.6/Conda/deps/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/jabou/.julia/v0.6/Conda/deps/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 72, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
```

I tested the `PyCall` package and I obtained these informations:

```
INFO: Testing PyCall
INFO: Python version 2.7.14 from /home/jabou/.julia/v0.6/Conda/deps/usr/lib/libpython2.7, PYTHONHOME=/home/jabou/.julia/v0.6/Conda/deps/usr:/home/jabou/.julia/v0.6/Conda/deps/usr
ENV[PYTHONPATH]=
ENV[PYTHONHOME]=
ENV[PYTHONEXECUTABLE]=
INFO: PyCall tests passed
```

More over, I defined the environment variable:

```
ENV["PYTHONPATH"] = "/home/jabou/.julia/v0.6/Conda/deps/usr/lib/libpython2.7"

ENV["PYTHONHOME"]= "/home/jabou/.julia/v0.6/Conda/deps/usr:/home/jabou/.julia/v0.6/Conda/deps/usr"
```

but nothing has changed...

Comment: The key to the `ENV` dict should be a string, you are trying to index it with a variable called `PYTHONPATH`, which is undefined. Try `ENV["PYTHONPATH"] = "/home/.../libpython2.7"`.

Comment: It worked for the `PYTHONPATH`  but I have still the same first error...

Comment: No wonder you can't use your python code in Julia without declaring all the paths & installing required dependencies

Comment: For sure, but I thought all the dependencies were installed... Do you know how I can install them, or maybe a command to see the dependencies ?

Comment: As a side note, you have TensorFlow in Julia: https://github.com/malmaud/TensorFlow.jl

Comment: Just to be sure, can you try running `import tensorflow` in your Python version 2.7.14 directly? If you get an import error there too, you need to `pip install` the tensorflow library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

I imported python correctly by adding `/lib/` to the `ENV[PYTHONHOME]`

After that, I imported the `layers` module with the following commands:

```
 @pyimport  tensorflow
 @pyimport tensorflow.contrib.layers as lay
```

And now, I can use the functions:

```
lay.batch_norm
PyObject <function batch_norm at 0x7f4738791938>
```